# How to generate suggestions to user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, Maybe that topic was too unclear. It's really hard to explain. What I actually want is:

> When the user types something in an input field, I want to generate some suggestions exactly like that the Stackoverflow suggests **jQuery** and **javascript** when we type **"j"**.

Does that make any sense? I am making a Stationery Web App. It needs to suggest **pen**, **pencil**, etc. when user types **"p"**?

I want it because that's too user-friendly. But, can't get to any near of it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can try it with a datalist

Comment: FYI, what you are describing is called an auto-complete control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, We did something similar. I can give you the source code, but the embarrasing thing is you didn't even start a code and completely wanted someone else to do it. Anyway here's a complete code:

- [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/tWg56/)
- [Git](https://github.com/akitech/sample_works/blob/master/adding_items.html)

All you need to do is: (Only a percent of code -- See complete source code for details and id and classes used below --):

```
$("#place").keyup(function foo(){
    $("#suggestions").show(200);
    $("#suggestions").html("");
    var thisPlace = $("#place").val();


    var suggestedPlaces = [];
    for(i= 0; i<placeArray.length; i++){
        var pointed = placeArray[i];
        if (pointed.indexOf(thisPlace) >= 0){
                suggestedPlaces.push(placeArray[i]);
        }
    }


    for(i= 0; i<suggestedPlaces.length; i++){
        $("#suggestions").append("<span class='place' id='"+suggestedPlaces[i]+"'>"+suggestedPlaces[i]+"</span>");
    }
    if (suggestedPlaces.length == 0){
            $("#suggestions").html("Sorry. No Results Found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly as I wanted buddy. I am not a PRO. So, had to. :D

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do it with the 'autocomplete' function.

Here is the link: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I show you my example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Town: <input type="text" name="town" id="town" />
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#town').autocomplete({source:'search_town.php', minLength:2});
  });
</script>
```

And the 'search_town.php':

```
<?php
  if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['term'] ) ) {
    exit;
  }

  require("dbconnect.php");

  $data = array();
  $term = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_REQUEST['term'] );

  $sql = "SELECT name, postcode FROM town WHERE lower(name) LIKE lower('$term%') ORDER BY name";
  $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ) or trigger_error( mysqli_error( $conn ) );

  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $result ) ) {
    $data[] = array(
      'label' => $row->name.' ('.$row->postcode.')',
      'value' => $row->name
    );
  }

  mysqli_free_result( $result );

  echo json_encode( $data );
  flush();
?>
```